# Using a stack to solve a maze Object Oriented (backtracking) issue

Tags: java, stack, maze

I am trying to solve a maze in an object oriented way.

My maze consists of fields, each field has an element attribute,
an element is a wall, player, helper or endpoint.  A field with an empty attribute is a path.

Each field keeps track of his own neighbors in a HashMap.

When the player hits a helper, the helper should solve the maze and show the correct path.

I'm trying to find the endpoint by getting the current location of the helper and storing it's neighbors fields  in a stack.

This is the code as far as helper goes.
The loop never ends, and I don't know why?

```
public void findRoute() {

    Collection<Field> c = currentField.getHashMap().values();
    Stack<Field> fieldNeighbours = new Stack<Field>();
    for (Field field : c) {

        fieldNeighbours.push(field);

    }

    while (!endpointReached) {

        Field p = fieldNeighbours.pop();

        if (p.getElement().getNaam().equals("endPoint")) {

            System.out.println("endPoint Reached! ");
            endpointReached = true;
            return;

        }

        if (!p.getElement().getNaam().equals("Wall")) {

            if (!p.getHashMap().get("north").getElement().getNaam().equals("Wall")) {

                fieldNeighbours.push(p.getHashMap().get("north"));


            }
            if (!p.getHashMap().get("south").getElement().getNaam().equals("Wall")) {

                fieldNeighbours.push(p.getHashMap().get("south"));

            }
            if (!p.getHashMap().get("east").getElement().getNaam().equals("Wall")) {

                fieldNeighbours.push(p.getHashMap().get("east"));

            }
            if (!p.getHashMap().get("west").getElement().getNaam().equals("wall")) {

                fieldNeighbours.push(p.getHashMap().get("west"));


            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: You need a way to mark whether or not a spot has been visited before. Think of mazes like a really long tree structure, that might help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the stack you need a set of already-visited cells to avoid searching cycles repeatedly.

I'll also point out that using hashes rather than simple references is bad design for most purposes.

Comment: So a second stack that keeps track of the visited fields?

Comment: I got it working. The second part is finding the shortest path. Can you recommend me a simple algorithm that i can implement?